# Automatic addition of trailing slash to urlencoded urls

Tags: php, hyperlink, urlencode

I am very confused about the following:

```
echo("<a href='http://".urlencode("www.test.com/test.php?x=1&y=2")."'>test</a><br>");

echo("<a href='http://"."www.test.com/test.php?x=1&y=2"."'>test</a>");
```

The first link gets a trailing slash added (that's causing me problems)
The second link does not.

Can anyone help me to understand why.
Clearly it appears to be something to do with urlencode, but I can't find out what.

Thanks
c

Comment: Don't thank C for PHP! :P (though technically you could).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be using `urlencode()` to echo URLs, unless they contain some non standard characters.

The example provided doesn't contain anything unusual.

### Example

```
$query = 'hello how are you?';

echo 'http://example.com/?q=' . urlencode($query);
// Ouputs http://example.com/?q=hello+how+are+you%3F
```

See I used it because the `$query` variable may contain spaces, question marks, etc. I can not use the question mark because it denotes the start of a query string, e.g. `index.php?page=1`.

In fact, that example would be better off just being output rather than `echo`'d.

Also, when I tried your example code, I did **not** get a traling slash, in fact I got

```
<a href='http://www.test.com%2Ftest.php%3Fx%3D1%26y%3D2'>test</a>
```

Comment: Thanks all, I see now from what you've all said and some testing that the server is obviously adding a trailing slash when it sees a domain level url.When I encode the whole url (I should have read the isntructions better) I hide the fact that the URL is a file level request which would normally not have a trailing slash added. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> string urlencode  ( string $str  )
>
> This function is convenient when
>   encoding a string to be **used in a
>   query part of a URL**, as a convenient
>   way to pass variables to the next
>   page.

Your `urlencode` is not used properly in your case.

Plus, `echo` don't usually come with `()` it should be `echo "<a href='http [...]</a>";`

Comment: Correct, because `echo` is a language construct, *not* a function.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `urlencode()` for parameters *only*! Example:

```
echo 'http://example.com/index.php?some_link='.urlencode('some value containing special chars like whitespace');
```

You can use this to pass URLs, etc. to your URL.